# Devise - Configuring the Routes fine for Controller Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here's what I added to my config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:invitations => "invitations", :sessions => "sessions"}
```

This doesn't work, if I try to sign in I get a template missing error.

How do you configure this for controller inheritance for invitations and sessions? And make the routes in the controller like "sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)" still work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is you are pulling the controllers out of the devise folder but you are leaving the views inside of the devise folder for the sessions and invitations.

You need to pull the respective views out of the devise folder and into their own folders.

So you views folder should have a folder called invitations and then the new.html.erb or edit.html.erb for invitations within that folder.

Just do the same thing for the Sessions folder. Pull it into the Views folder instead of the Views/devise/ folder.

I hope this is clear. Answer back if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really like not to have to do that? That gets real messy. are you sure that's required?

Comment: Yeah that's how i've done it in a few apps. I believe that it is required but let me know if you find another way. I figure that devise creates a namespace for itself and therefore, it has its own "devise" folder in views and controllers. There's no way to take the controllers out of that and still stay within that folder in the views.

Comment: (I couldn't edit the last comment) Also, I usually take the folder out of the devise folder completely so its only in one place instead of 2.